# What is the additional structure present in homogeneous polynomials when used in representation theory?

Tags: representation-theory

Representation theory of $SU(2)$ uses homogeneous polynomials in two variables of degree $n$ for the vector spaces which are used to represent the actions of group elements.

I am trying to understand the reason for this. Since the homogeneous polynomials form complex vector spaces themselves, they are isomorphic to some ${\mathbb C}^n$. So why not use ${\mathbb C}^n$ for this purpose? Obviously there is **some** additional property which comes in handy. I am interested in knowing **what** this property is, because the use of these homogeneous polynomials, for me, comes way too much as unobvious surprise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're certainly correct that any finite-dimensional complex vector space is isomorphic (as complex vector space) to some $\mathbb C^n$... so there's no *necessity* of modeling those repns in terms of polynomials.

However, there is a small advantage, namely, that spaces of homogeneous polynomials in two variables do model "symmetric powers" of a two-dimensional vector space, in a fashion that is compatible with the group action... and without having to talk about "symmetric powers" or "tensor products" or other multi-linear algebra before starting. That is, we can look at those irreducibles right away... rather than post-poning it till after more apparatus is set up.

That is, the action $SU(2)$ induces on the homogeneous degree $n$ polynomials from the matrix action on the "indeterminates" $x,y$ *is*
the symmetric-power action/representation... without having to define it otherwise. :)

Comment: Just the property I was looking for. As usual I get irritated when I do not see _which_ part of a machinery is used when the instrument is introduced.